# Would it be efficient to sort with indexes

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, performance, sorting

So I was thinking of a new sorting algorithm that might be efficient but I am not too sure about that.

> 1) Imagine we have an array a of only positive numbers.
>   2) We go through the array and find the biggest number n.
>   3) We create a new array b of the size n+1.
>   4) We go through every entry in the unsorted array and increase the value in the second array at the index of the number of the unsorted array we are looking at by one. (In pseudo-code this means: b[a[i]]++; while a[i] is the number we are currently looking at)
>   5) Once we have done this with every element in a, the array b stores at every index the exact amount of numbers of this index. (For example: b[0] = 3 means that we had 3 zeros in the initial array a)
>   6) We go through the whole array b and skip all the empty fields and create a new List or Array out of it.

So I can imagine that this algorithm can be very fast and efficient for smaller numbers only since at the end we have to go through the whole array b to build the sorted one, which is going to be really time consuming.
If we for example have an array a = {1000, 1} it would still check 1001 elements in array b wether or not they are 0 even though we only have 2 elements in the initial array.

With smaller numbers however we should almost get a O(n) result? I am not too sure about that and that's why I am asking you. Maybe I am even missing something really important. 
Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: It's called a [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations on independently re-discovering the [*counting sort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

This is indeed a very good sorting strategy for situations when the range is limited, and the number of items is significantly greater than the number of items in your array.

In situations when the range is greater than the number of items in the array a traditional sorting algorithm would give you better performance.

Algorithms of this kind are called [*pseudo-polynomial*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry, but I didn't know that this algorithm already existed just like I described it.

Answer (score 1):

> we should almost get a O(n) result

You get O(N+M) result, when M - max number in first array. Plus, you spend O(M) memory, so it have sense only if M is small. See [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)